# 404 error constantly encountered when working with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

when I run the website on any browser, the typical 404 error "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." regardless of what I route it to or if I route it at all. I have checked, and everything seems to be in the right place, but I have no idea what is causing the error, especially as I have tried every fix I have found online.

My `route.py` file is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from blog import app, db
from blog.models import User, Post
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    posts = Post.query.all()
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')
```

The WSGI is:

```
from blog import app as application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the `__init__.py` file is:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'be35984218226b31d6ca0bf1ccefdaf78e47c9181177a41a'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'blog.db')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from blog import routes
```

Thanks in advance for any advice given

Comment: perhaps you could post your directory structure.

Comment: This code won't run the server correctly, as posted. Please show your actual code as a [mcve]. There's no point in bringing in database models until you can prove that you can make a request. Remove these distractions. Why are you making (at least) 3 apps? Are you sure the one you've imported and run is the one with the routes? Why are you overwriting imports like `app`? To debug, I'd start with a simple, single app.py file with nothing but a flask import, a single route and an app.run call and see if you can connect to that. Then add multiple files once you get that working. Proceed slowly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that could be going wrong:

- Your Firewall is blocking the flask app
- You entered the wrong IP Address.

If you entered the wrong IP Address, use this IP instead: localhost:5000.
A better alternative would be to use this app.run function instead

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=ENTER YOUR DESIRED PORT HERE)
```

If the firewall is the issue, stackoverflow isn't the right place :/